# When R cannot be generated for some reason where is this reason/cause indicated?

Tags: android

Sometimes R cannot be generated. Fine.  But where is the error message describing what prevented R from being generated?

In eclipse problems all I see is that the R cannot be found. I don't see any messages anywhere saying why it was not generated.  This is absurd.

Comment: Clean your project. If that doesn't work, check your `/res` folder. The problem mostly lies in the xml code.

Comment: my point is there must be something it did not like. Why does it not report the error?

Comment: I know what you mean. `R cannot be generated` error makes eclipse look like I stepped on a mine in minesweeper.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse go to Windows>ShowView>Problems -The error should be shown in this view

Comment: not so. its does not give the reason.

Answer (score 0):

That means resources failed to compile, such as menu or layout resources. If you rebuild the project (Project >> Clean in Eclipse) it'll output any compilation errors, and R will generate if you rebuild again after fixing those errors.

Comment: No not really. It does not show the cause.

Comment: @gitright did you try re-creating the project and copying your code/resources over? That worked for me a few times when this happened